# Translate user query in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Dialogflow agent is matching intents accurately, but I want to use the same agent to recognize other languages and match the proper intents.

I'm using actions on google and dialogflow, I'm using webhook for most of the intents which i developed in nodejs using actions-on-google npm library.

I tried dialogflow middleware to detect the language of the user query and then convert into English language, but middleware is triggered after intent matching.

So what I want to achieve is convert the user query into English first then match one of the intent.

Comment: Is creating a multilingual agent not an option? https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-multilingual

Comment: i'm not sure how it works

Comment: It allows you to trigger your created intents using a different language, so this way you dont have to do any translations to language A. You can create seperate training phrases, intent responses and entities for language B. If your user talks to your agent in language B then it will use the agent you created for language B. Everything to get started should be in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah you should create a multilingual agent. Otherwise you're going to run into trouble with entity matching. The Middleware happens after Dialogflow, you can't get before Dialogflow.